# Creating multi-layered subtotals of pandas Data Frame (similar to Excel)

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a pandas data frame and want to subtotal by 'State' first and then add a second-tier subtotal by 'ProductName2' (similar to how you can make subtotals in Excel).

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.DataFrame()  

df.insert(0, "State", ['FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA']) 
df.insert(1, 'ProductName2',['Advil', 'Advil', 'Mucinex', 'Solosec', 'Advil', 'Advil', 'Mucinex', 
                             'Mucinex', 'Advil', 'Advil', 'Advil']) 
df.insert(2, 'Units', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 2]) 
df.insert(3, 'Scripts', [5, 7, 6, 4, 2, 9, 
                         10, 2, 6, 7, 12]) 
df.insert(4, 'Total Amount', [1, 54, 321, 45, 89, 48, 23, 56, 9, 26, 32])  

result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)  

for state in df['State'].unique():     
    product_rows = df[df['State'] == state]     
 
    units_subtotal = product_rows['Units'].sum()     
    script_subtotal = product_rows['Scripts'].sum()     
    total_amount_subtotal = product_rows['Total Amount'].sum()

      result_df = pd.concat([result_df, product_rows,                            
                           pd.DataFrame(                                
                               [[f'{state} Subtotal', '', units_subtotal,                                                       
                                 script_subtotal, total_amount_subtotal]],                                 
                                 columns=df.columns)]                           
                         )     

result_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  

print(result_df)
```

I then get the following output:

```
          State ProductName2 Units Scripts Total Amount
0            FL        Advil     1       5            1
1            FL        Advil     2       7           54
2            FL      Mucinex     3       6          321
3            FL      Solosec     4       4           45
4   FL Subtotal                 10      22          421
5            GA        Advil     5       2           89
6            GA        Advil     6       9           48
7            GA      Mucinex     7      10           23
8            GA      Mucinex     8       2           56
9   GA Subtotal                 26      23          216
10           LA        Advil     9       6            9
11           LA        Advil     4       7           26
12           LA        Advil     2      12           32
13  LA Subtotal                 15      25           67
```

I want to be able to get subtotals for the similar 'ProductName2's for each state. I've tried adding in a second 'concat' function but I can't grab unique ProductName2s for each individual state.

This is my desired output:

```
          State ProductName2 Units Scripts Total Amount
0            FL        Advil     1       5            1
1            FL        Advil     2       7           54
2            FL  Advil Total     3       12          55
3            FL      Mucinex     3       6          321
4            FL Mucinex Total    3       6          321
5            FL      Solosec     4       4           45
6            FL Solosec Total    4       4           45
7   FL Subtotal                 10      22          421
# And so on for the following states...
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same algorithm as yours to generate the sub-sub-totals. Here is an example using a list to store the rows before concatenation.

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    
    df.insert(0, "State", ['FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'GA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA'])
    df.insert(1, 'ProductName2',['Advil', 'Advil', 'Mucinex', 'Solosec', 'Advil', 'Advil', 'Mucinex',
                                 'Mucinex', 'Advil', 'Advil', 'Advil'])
    df.insert(2, 'Units', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 2])
    df.insert(3, 'Scripts', [5, 7, 6, 4, 2, 9,
                             10, 2, 6, 7, 12])
    df.insert(4, 'Total Amount', [1, 54, 321, 45, 89, 48, 23, 56, 9, 26, 32])
    
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    
    for state in df['State'].unique():
        bystate_rows = df[df['State'] == state]
        l = []
        for product_name2 in bystate_rows['ProductName2'].unique():
            product_rows = bystate_rows[bystate_rows['ProductName2'] == product_name2]
            l.append(product_rows)
    
            units_subtotal = product_rows['Units'].sum()
            script_subtotal = product_rows['Scripts'].sum()
            total_amount_subtotal = product_rows['Total Amount'].sum()
            subtotal_row = pd.DataFrame(
                                       [[state, f'{product_name2} Total', units_subtotal,
                                         script_subtotal, total_amount_subtotal]],
                                         columns=df.columns)
            l.append(subtotal_row)
    
    
        units_subtotal = bystate_rows['Units'].sum()
        script_subtotal = bystate_rows['Scripts'].sum()
        total_amount_subtotal = bystate_rows['Total Amount'].sum()
        subtotal_row = pd.DataFrame(
                                   [[f'{state} Subtotal', '', units_subtotal,
                                     script_subtotal, total_amount_subtotal]],
                                     columns=df.columns)
        l.append(subtotal_row)
    
        result_df = pd.concat([result_df] + l)
    
    result_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    
    print(result_df)
```

If you need to do that with many 3, 4 or more sub totals, I suggest you to turn this code into a recursive function.

Comment: I swear the coders on here are wizards... thank you so much this worked perfectly! Great idea of storing rows before concatenation.